# ioctl equivalent of iproute2/bridge commands

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ioctl, bridge, vlan

I want to do an ioctl equivalent for following iproute2 command:

Following commands have no brctl equivalent, hence unable to find ioctl equivalent:

- ip link set eth0 master Bridge
- bridge  vlan del vid 1 dev eth0
- bridge vlan add vid 101 dev Ethernet0

I need to issue ioctl as netlink is not supported.

ip link set eth0 master Bridge -> is equivalent to brctl addif <bridge_name> 
i got equivalent ioctl from strace.

Comment: It's called **netlink** protocol. A lot of documentation is available over the internet. Otherwise if it's still working (having some kind of fallback), you can always look into the source code -- this is a power of Open Source -- and see how it's done.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks.I was able to write an equivalent for "ip link set eth0 master Bridge" . but when I tried looking for a function in netlink protocol to set vlan filter for bridge interface.
We have a function "rtnl_link_bridge_get_port_vlan" to get port vlan but no such function to set it . are there any such function ?

Comment: Are you using `libnl`? It has a lot of APIs regarding to VLAN.

Comment: Yes I'm using libnl, it has apis related vlan but for subinterface not for "bridge vlan".
I referred to iproute2 code and was able to get the required code.
Thanks.